# hosting multiple sites on Amazon ec2 but got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I tried to host multiple sites on Amazon ec2 using nginx on different port connecting(port 80, and 81), but I only can access the site with port 80.

first, I set up security group on amazon EC2 console (port 80 and 81) as following picture.
[security groups setting on Amazon EC2 console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chKxm.png)

and I set up nginx.config on remote ubuntu server as follows:[nginx.conf setting on remote ubuntu server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs8HZ.png)

I tried to switch sites with different ports, but always the site with port 80 can be accessed and I cannot access the website on port 81 with ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I could not figure out what happened. How can I debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you using? I remember RedHat Linux had iptables running in addition to Amazon security groups. Can you ssh to the box and run something like `wget http://localhost:81` and see if you get results?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. I can get results by "wget http://localhost:81". But I got timeout ERROR with http://[ip]:81

Comment: I could launch my website on my mobile phone! I think the problem might be the firewall setting on my local network.